# Sum of the reciprocals of the odds (alternating)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I've been trying to work out what the following infinite series converges to:
$$\frac{1}{1} - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{9} - \frac{1}{11}...$$
But evaluating something like this is still new to me, and I haven't found any answers online (perhaps I'm not googling well enough?).So my question is, what value does it converge to and how is it derived?

Comment: Have you seen the Taylor series for arctan?

Comment: @kenta-s Oh thank you, I just remembered that exists.
I feel a little silly now lol

Comment: Hope this helps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @KentaS, you can proceed as follows (for $|x| < 1$):
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1 - x} = 1 + x + x^{2} + x^{3} & \Rightarrow \frac{1}{1 + x^{2}} = 1 - x^{2} + x^{4} - x^{6} + \ldots\\\\
& \Rightarrow \arctan(x) = x - \frac{x^{3}}{3} + \frac{x^{5}}{5} - \frac{x^{7}}{7} + \ldots\\\\
& \Rightarrow \frac{\pi}{4} = 1 - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{7} + \ldots
\end{align*}

It is worth mentioning that, even though the geometric series does not converge for $x = 1$, the expression deduced for $\arctan$ also holds true when $x = 1$. To conclude so, it suffices to apply the Leibniz test as suggested by @Hussain-Alqatari in the comments.

Hopefully this helps!